# how to get the recipient_id using this PublicActivity ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using the PublicActivity gem and this was created in my database

schema.db

```
create_table "activities", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "trackable_id"
    t.string   "trackable_type"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "owner_type"
    t.string   "key"
    t.text     "parameters"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.string   "recipient_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     :null => false
  end
```

I am able to track all posts that are happening inside my website by using this inside the post.rb model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked except: :destroy, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
end
```

By doing this, I can get the owner_id. What do I need to set `recipient:` to make it grab the value? Right now recipient_id is nil.

I want to ultimately use something like this in my view `<%= link_to activity.recipient_id.name %>` to get the name of the recipient where the activity was made to

I'm trying to set it to either the post_id or user_id but I'm getting an undefined local variable or method error.

Here's the table of the model that I'm tracking

```
create_table "postcomments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text      "content"
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.integer   "post_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at",      :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.text      "comment_content"
  end
```

Comment: What is the `recipient`?

Comment: @nextstep did you ever figure this out....I am also trying to set the recipient ID

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the Model

assuming recipient_id is the user of tracked object. Otherwise change model.user as per your application

```
tracked recipient: ->(controller, model) { model && model.user }
```